# Boundary condition incompatibilities in *coupled* PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Regarding incompatibilities between boundary conditions and
initial values in PDEs, I mostly find discussions about the "corner
problem", i.e. the initial data at the boundary violating the
boundary conditions (in form of jumps or weaker
discontinuities).

For *coupled* PDEs an IMHO different type of incompatibility
puzzles me at the moment. A particularly simple examples reads
\begin{align*}
  u_t&=v_{xx}\\
  v_t&=-u_{xx}
            \quad.
\end{align*}
where $u$ and $v$ are $[0,2\pi]\times\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$.

With, case (i), the initial values
\begin{equation*}
  u(x,0)=v(x,0)=\sin x
\end{equation*}
and the boundary
conditions 
\begin{equation*}
  u(0,t)=u(2\pi,t)=v(0,t)=v(2\pi,t)=0
  \quad,
\end{equation*}
the solution is readily found:
\begin{align*}
  u(x,t)&=(\cos t-\sin t)\,\sin x\\
  v(x,t)&=(\cos t+\sin t)\,\sin x
\end{align*}

But hoping for a similar success for case (ii), namely
\begin{equation*}
  u(x,0)=\sin x
  \quad\text{and}\quad
 v(x,0)=\cos x
\end{equation*}
with 
\begin{equation*}
  u(0,t)=u(2\pi,t)=0
  \quad\text{and}\quad 
  v(0,t)=v(2\pi,t)=1
\end{equation*}
is in vain: While the (putative) solution
\begin{align*}
  u(x,t)&=\cos t\,\sin x-\sin t\cos x\\
  v(x,t)&=\cos t\,\cos x+\sin t\sin x
\end{align*}
obeys the initial values, it violates the boundary conditions for
$\frac{t}{2\pi}\not\in\mathbb Z$. Actually, rewriting it as
\begin{align*}
  u(x,t)&=\sin(x-t)\\
  v(x,t)&=\cos(x-t)
\end{align*}
makes it particularly clear that in this case no (separate, spatial,
stationary) boundary conditions can be imposed on $u$ and $v$.

Are there any key words for this type of incompatibility?

What also puzzles me: "Solving" the problem (ii) numerically, there is
convergence (regarding ever finer discretization) for finite $t$. But
the obtained $u$ and $v$ are solutions to *which problem*?